# Strings not being compared? Or input correctly?

Tags: c, string, fgets, strcmp

This is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char userService1[50];
   char userService2[50];

   int price1;
   int price2;


   printf("Davy's auto shop services\n\n");
   printf("Select first service:\n");
   fgets(userService1,13,stdin);
   printf("Select second service:\n\n");
   fgets(userService2,13,stdin);
   printf("Davy's auto shop invoice\n\n");

   if(strcmp(userService1,"Oil change") == 0){
    printf("Service 1: Oil change, $35\n"); 
    price1 = 35; 
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Tire rotation") == 0){
    printf("Service 1: Tire rotation, $19\n"); 
    price1 = 19;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Car wash") == 0 ){
    printf("Service 1: Car wash, $7\n");
    price1 = 7;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService1,"Car wax") == 0 ){
    printf("Service 1: Car wax, $12\n");  
    price1 = 12;
   }

   else{
      printf("Service 1: No service\n");
      price1 = 0;
   }

   if(strcmp(userService2,"Oil") == 0){
      printf("Service 2: Oil change, $35\n\n");
      price2 = 35;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService2,"Tire") == 0 ){
      printf("Service 2: Tire rotation, $19\n\n");
      price2 = 19;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService2,"Car") == 0 ){
      printf("Service 2: Car wash, $7\n\n");
      price2 = 7;
   }

   else if(strcmp(userService2,"Car") == 0 ){
      printf("Service 2: Car wax, $12\n\n");
      price2 = 12;
   }
   else{
      printf("Service 2: No service\n\n");
      price2 = 0;
   }

   int price = price1 + price2;
   printf("Total: $%d\n", price);
   return 0;
 }
```

This is what is being outputted with the current version:

```
Davy's auto shop services
Oil change -- $35
Tire rotation -- $19
Car wash -- $7
Car wax -- $12

Select first service:
Select second service:

Davy's auto shop invoice

Service 1: No service
Service 2: No service

Total: $0
```

with the intput:

```
 Oil change 
 Car wax
```

This is the desired output for the code:

```
Davy's auto shop services
Oil change -- $35
Tire rotation -- $19
Car wash -- $7
Car wax -- $12

Select first service:
Select second service:

Davy's auto shop invoice

Service 1: Oil change, $35
Service 2: Car wax, $12

Total: $47
```

I'm not sure if the strings are being assigned incorrectly with `fgets()`or, if the strings aren't being compared correctly. Either way I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: you need to trim the `\n` from `fgets`. ie: `fgets` returns inputted string with `\n` appended at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: Note: This is a great time to learn how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line, checking variable contents etc to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Also, consider using 50 as `fgets`'s second argument as both the arrays are of size 50

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that fgets reads "\n" at the end of the string

A quick fix would be to include it in your comparison:

```
if(strcmp(userService1,"Oil change\n") == 0){
    printf("Service 1: Oil change, $35\n"); 
    price1 = 35; 
}
```

Or you can cut out the "\n" entirely like so:

```
if(strcmp(strtok(userService1,"\n"),"Oil change") == 0){
    printf("Service 1: Oil change, $35\n"); 
    price1 = 35; 
}
```

Both solutions gave the intended result.